# How can I make ffmpeg executable file separately by using gcc command?

Tags: qt, gcc, ffmpeg

actually, my goal is to use ffmpeg on Qt platform. But tow of them is unfamiliar with me..
I tried command on ./ffmpeg directory after build (./configure, make, sudo make install) as below on Mac (os x) 10.12.4 (Sierra)

$ gcc ffmpeg.c -o a.out -I /usr/local/include -I /Users/koseonjae/ffmpeg -L /usr/local/lib -lavdevice -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lx264 -lvpx -lvorbisenc -lvorbis -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg -lmp3lame -lbz2 -lz -lxslt -lfdk-aac -liconv -lopus -lx265 -lxvidcore -lpng16 -lswresample -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices -framework AudioUnit -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreAudio -framework Foundation -framework Security -framework VideoDecodeAcceleration -framework VideoToolbox

I added many library, but result is as below

/Users/koseonjae/ffmpeg/ffmpeg2.h:157:8: error: unknown type name 'BOOL'
static BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType);

/Users/koseonjae/ffmpeg/ffmpeg2.h:157:19: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
static BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType);

---

what library should I add?? thank you!

Comment: That's a compiler error, not a linker error. Adding all the libraries in the world will not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not about Qt, but about compiling ffmpeg on a Mac.
Read on about detailed installation of ffmpeg dependencies: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX .